# High CPU on Windows 10 (system/ntoskrl.exe)

Tags: windows-10, performance, troubleshooting, cpu-usage

**UPDATE: Fixed with Insider Build 17713.rs5_release.180706-1551**

Recently my "System" process keeps using ~20% CPU.
Process Explorer shows busy threads of ntoskrnl.exe!RtlAvlInsertNodeEx+0x370.
Some forum post suggested that Hyper-V VM is causing it but uninstalling docker and disabling Hyper-V didnt help.

Process Explorer screenshot is attached
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with Insider Build 17713.rs5_release.180706-1551

Answer (score 2):

To solve the problem, we can try the following method:
**Step1**: Go to "Task Scheduler (Local)->Task Scheduler Library->Microsoft->Windows->MemoryDiagnostic"

Make "ProcessMemoryDiagnosticEvents" and "RunFullMemoryDiagnostic" disabled.

[image]

**Step2**:Go to "Task Scheduler (Local)->Task Scheduler Library->Microsoft->Windows->.NET Framework"

Make ".NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319" and ".NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319 critical" disabled ( if there are more options in the "Name" column, make all of them disabled ).

[image]

Comment: It didnt solve anything.

Answer (score 1):

Running Chrome on WIn 10 and when opening web pages Lsass.exe use 20+% of CPU continuously...No good answer but I have found a way to reduce the problem :
1) Open up procexp as administrator
2) click on Lsass.exe
3) click on properties
4) wait for a TID to start using 15-25% of CPU cycles
5) select that TID and hit suspend

This really works, only bad news is that you have to hit resume when doing other things than surfing on Chrome...Often times selecting an icon on your desktop won't open until you hit resume for that specific TID.

BTW, running procexp as administrator when you first login tend to prevent some the Lsass.exe high cpu activity.

This is a cluge, but no other suggestion can keep Lsass.exe in check.